# Simplified JQuery Autcomplete solution for multiple fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json

i just made my first successful integration of jquery's autocomplete, to return and filter results from the mysql database in my rails 3 app as you type into a number of text fields in a couple different forms for different tables.

it works tremendously, but is definitely an inefficient code setup. i spent some time trying to write it the correct way, but i just couldn't get it right; a little too far beyond my current skill level.

**i thought i'd post the solution here for those newbies still looking (as even this was a bit difficult for me), and to see if anyone could recommend/guide us thru some tips for simplifying it properly?**

(this is also my first SO contribution; i finally felt i had something worthy, so please excuse any newbie mistakes)

**in my gemfile;**

```
group :assets do
     gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

then make sure all gems are installed.

**in my application.css file, which is included in the necessary views;**

```
*= require jquery.ui.all
```

**in the associated controller file for one form;**

```
  # GET /auto_custom_method1.json
  def auto_custom_method1
    render :json => Model.where("database_column_name1 LIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").map(&:database_column_name1).uniq
  end

  # GET /auto_custom_method2.json
  def auto_custom_method2
    render :json => Model.where("database_column_name2 LIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").map(&:database_column_name2).uniq
  end

  # GET /auto_custom_method3.json
  def auto_custom_method3
    render :json => Model.where("database_column_name3 LIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").map(&:database_column_name3).uniq
  end

  # GET /auto_custom_method4.json
  def auto_custom_method4
    render :json => Model.where("database_column_name4 LIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").map(&:database_column_name4).uniq
  end

  # GET /auto_custom_method5.json
  def auto_custom_method5
    render :json => Model.where("database_column_name5 LIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").map(&:database_column_name5).uniq
  end
```

**in the associated controller file for another form;**

```
# GET /auto_custom_method6.json
  def auto_custom_method6
    render :json => Model.where("database_column_name5 LIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").map(&:database_column_name6).uniq
  end

  # GET /auto_custom_method7.json
  def auto_custom_method7
    render :json => Model.where("database_column_name5 LIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").map(&:database_column_name7).uniq
  end

  # GET /auto_custom_method8.json
  def auto_custom_method8
    render :json => Model.where("database_column_name5 LIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").map(&:database_column_name8).uniq
  end
```

**in my application.js file, which is included in the necessary views;**

model_name, auto_custom_method, and #field_id are all customized according to your unique application.

```
//= require query
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all

$(function() {
    $.getJSON("/model_name1/auto_custom_method1", function(data) {
        $("#field_id1").autocomplete({
            source: data,
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
});
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("/model_name1/auto_custom_method2", function(data) {
        $("#field_id2").autocomplete({
            source: data,
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
});
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("/model_name1/auto_custom_method3", function(data) {
        $("#field_id3").autocomplete({
            source: data,
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
});
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("/model_name1/auto_custom_method4", function(data) {
        $("#field_id4").autocomplete({
            source: data,
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
});
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("/model_name1/auto_custom_method5", function(data) {
        $("#field_id5").autocomplete({
            source: data,
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
});
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("/model_name2/auto_custom_method6", function(data) {
        $("#field_id6").autocomplete({
            source: data,
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
});
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("/model_name2/auto_custom_method7", function(data) {
        $("#field_id7").autocomplete({
            source: data,
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
});
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("/model_name2/auto_custom_method8", function(data) {
        $("#field_id8").autocomplete({
            source: data,
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
});
```